# Using MOUT.js module with JSPM

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jspm

How do import a [MOUT](http://moutjs.com/) module, eg array equals, into a file using [JSPM](http://jspm.io/)?

Comment: Sorry for removing those tags, it just sounded as if you only had problems installing and using jspm, not to write ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to install the latest version from NPM:

```
jspm install npm:mout
```

and use it like this:

```
import equals from 'mout/array/equals';
console.log(equals([1], [2], function() {
  console.log(arguments);
}));
```